# Alguien sabe porque no me muestra correctamente la tabla php

Tags: javascript, php

La tabla y el span para poder mostrar los datos en una modal,
pero al momento de visualizar la tabla me sale asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este seria mi codigo

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
                    $consulta=pg_query($conexion,$sql);  

                    while($row = pg_fetch_array($consulta)){
                      ?>
                      <tr>
                        <td><span id="id_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['id_usu'];?></span></td>
                        <td><span id="nombre1_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre_1_usu'];?></span></td>
                        <td><span id="nombre2_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre_2_usu'];?></span></td>
                        <td><span id="apellido1_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['apellido_1_usu'];?></span></td>
                        <td><span id="apellido2_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['apellido_2_usu'];?></span></td>
                        <td><span id="documento_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['documento_usu'];?></span></td>
                        <td><span id="clave_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['clave'];?></span></td>
                        <td><span id="activo_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['activo'];?></span></td>
                        <td><span id="cargo_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['id_cargo'];?></span></td>
                                            
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success edit" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Editar</button></td>
                      
                      </tr>
                      <?php } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es porque llamas a cosas diferentes

```
<td><span id="id_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['id_usu'];?></span></td>
```

Una variable de esas es la correcta, imaginemos que es la primer forma, seria así

```
<td><span id="id_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['id'];?></span></td>
```

Yo preferiría hacerlo mejor con variables

```
$idUser = $row['id'];
<td><span id="id_<?php echo $idUser; ?>"><?php echo $idUser;?></span></td>
```

Y tienes muchas malas practicas en tu código, pero primero entiende y resuelve tu error.

Comment: Es al revez, lo correcto sería `id_usu`.

Comment: Si, cualquiera se fijaría que imprime el valor en el `span`, pero es que me gustó más la otra forma, más limpia la variable jeje (prefieroCamelCase a snake_case) pero solo es locura mía...